# How to add a Picture of my self with PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am writing a code , I want to add a picture of my self in my code using Qt functions , my code dis not made with class functions. I have tried but nothing helped me. I wrote this code in PyCharm. I want to add the picture with QtWidgets function or QtGui function or any function from pyqt5.

My Code :

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setGeometry(1200, 300, 500, 500)
    win.setWindowTitle("About my self")
    win.setWindowIcon(QIcon("app.jpg"))

    lbl_name1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    lbl_name1.setText("Name : Hit Arshibhai gojya")
    lbl_name1.adjustSize()
    lbl_name1.move(20, 20)

    lbl_name5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    lbl_name5.setText("Birth Date : 2.1.2010")
    lbl_name5.adjustSize()
    lbl_name5.move(20, 40)

    lbl_name2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    lbl_name2.setText("Age : 14")
    lbl_name2.adjustSize()
    lbl_name2.move(20, 60)

    lbl_name3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    lbl_name3.setText("Std. : 9")
    lbl_name3.adjustSize()
    lbl_name3.move(20, 80)

    lbl_name4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    lbl_name4.setText("School : N.P. BHalodiya High School")
    lbl_name4.adjustSize()
    lbl_name4.move(20, 100)

    lbl_name6 = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    lbl_name6.setText("Hobbies : Music, Games, Coding")
    lbl_name6.adjustSize()
    lbl_name6.move(20, 120)

    # I want to make a code to add my own picture over here.

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())



window()`
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you to use [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and not rely on fixed geometries. Also, as the [documentation explains](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework), a central widget should always be set on a QMainWindow, and any "child" widgets that are not part of the main window framework (menus, toolbars, etc.) should always be children of that central widget, which should have a layout set on its own. You cannot set a layout on QMainWindow, you have to set it on its central widget.